# pass output from pandas apply to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can I pass the output from `apply` to multiple columns?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def someFunc(x, y):
    return x**2, y**2

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(5, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])    
df.loc[:, ['c', 'd']] = np.zeros((5, 2)) # can pass array to df
df.loc[:, ['c', 'd']] = df.apply(lambda row: someFunc(row.a, row.b), axis=1)
```

In the example above I can pass an `array` to the two columns, but the output from `apply` is a `pd.series` of tuples which returns the error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need return `Series`:

```
def someFunc(x, y):
    return pd.Series([x**2, y**2])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(5, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])    

df[['c', 'd']] = df.apply(lambda row: someFunc(row.a, row.b), axis=1) 
print (df)
          a         b         c         d
0  0.145095  0.164194  0.021052  0.026960
1  0.141085  0.515790  0.019905  0.266040
2  0.416814  0.364209  0.173734  0.132648
3  0.025355  0.490520  0.000643  0.240610
4  0.938705  0.690380  0.881166  0.476624
```